# How to know which Django model is calling the property through the ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Inside the property I would like to know which model is calling it. Is there a way to do that?

Example code:

```
# Model One
class ServerOne(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    virtual_machine_server = models.ForeignKey(VirtualMachineServer)

# Model Two
class ServerTwo(models.Model):

    virtual_machine_server = models.ForeignKey(VirtualMachineServer)

# Model Three
class VirtualMachineServer(models.Model):

    @property
    def virtual_machine(self):
        # Execute the code based on which model 
        # is calling this property

        return vm
```

Both ServerOne and ServerTwo have VirtualMachineServer as a ForeignKey. I would like to call VirtualMachineServer's virtual_machine property on ServerOne or ServerTwo and execute the code based on which model is calling it

Example:

```
server_one = ServerOne.objects.get(pk=1)
vm = server_one.virtual_machine_server.virtual_machine

server_two = ServerTwo.objects.get(pk=2)
vm = server_two.virtual_machine_server.virtual_machine
```

I tried to create a custom Manager in ServerOne and ServerTwo:

```
class ServerOneManager(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        servers = super(ServerOneManager, self).get_query_set()
        for server in servers:
            server.virtual_machine_server.child_instance = vm

        return servers
```

And then look for the child_instance attribute in virtual_machine property:

```
@property
def virtual_machine(self):
    if not hasattr(self, "child_instance"):
        raise InstanceIsNotSetException()
```

But it didn't work.

Note: child_instance is not in the database, it's only dynamically created attribute.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If only one server points to the virtual machine server, then you can use a reverse lookup, e.g. with a [related name.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) So if ServerOne's ForeignKey to VirtualMachineServer has the related name `server_one` and ServerTwo's ForeignKey has `server_two`, then you can do something along the lines of

```
if self.server_one:
    # Do something
elif self.server_two:
    # Do something else
else:
    # No server!
```

ForeignKeys also automatically have a related name created by appending the suffix `_set`, e.g. `VirtualMachineServer.serverone_set.all()`.

Alternatively, if there are multiple objects with ForeignKeys to the VirtualMachineServer, then you could just add a parameter to `virtual_machine` that specifies what object is referring to it. Then you could act accordingly. For example:

```
server_one.virtual_machine_server.virtual_machine(server_one)
```